# Консоль NodeJS не реагирует на ввод команд

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

После `npm start` и запуска учебного примера я не могу ничего ввести в консоли. Приходится просто её закрывать, но когда запускаю по новой через `npm start` выдаёт ошибку

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\???????\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'C:\Users\???????\packag e.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!    
C:\Users\???????\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-12T18_36_3
1_735Z-debug.log
```

Спасает только удаление `my-app`, предварительно сохранив копии файлов `index.js` и `index.css`  и последующее пересоздание корневой папки `my-app`. Как решить проблему? И как пользоваться  командой `npm stop`? Прописывать в `package.json` ?

Comment: Если вы на  windows, остановить можно с помощью `ctrl+c`.

Comment: Да на тостере мне уже всё рассказали.. спасибо)